# supervisord superlance memmon not work

Tags: php, laravel-5, supervisord

supervisord.conf

```
[eventlistener:memmon]
command=/usr/local/bin/memmon -p system_message_dispatch=35MB
events=TICK_60

[program:system_message_dispatch]
command                 = php /mnt/www/project/artisan queue:work --queue=system_message_dispatch --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
process_name            = %(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs                = 6
autostart               = true
autorestart             = true
stdout_logfile          = /tmp/supervisor_system_message_dispatch.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stderr_logfile          = /tmp/supervisor_system_message_dispatch.err.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
```

my problem is:
when the program system_message_dispatch's RSS exceed 35MB, this program don't restart, but memmon have response

```
supervisor> tail memmon
READY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
```